# Getting error:(Element not interactable) when sending keys into the input field in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am getting error (element not interactable) when I am trying to send keys into the input field. When I am trying to only click the input filed I am able to do but when giving text it is showing error I have so many things to solve this but I am getting this error only.

My code:

````
from selenium import webdriver

Driver=webdriver.Chrome() 
Driver=get('https://YouTube.com') 
Box=Driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search-input"]')
Box.send_keys('music') ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The searchbar is input(id=search) in div class(search-input). Try this;

```
from selenium import webdriver

Driver=webdriver.Chrome() 
Driver.get('https://YouTube.com') 
Box=Driver.find_element_by_id('search-input').find_element_by_id('search')
Box.send_keys('music')
```

Answer (score 2):

To send elements to the search box. First induce a wait for the element to be clickable due to page load.

```
Box=WebDriverWait(Driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#search")))
Box.send_keys('music')
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

Driver=webdriver.Chrome() 
Driver=get('https://YouTube.com') 
Box=Driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/ytd-app/div/div/ytd-masthead/div[3]/div[2]/ytd-searchbox/form/div/div[1]/input')
Box.send_keys('music')
```